# Fatal: Failed to read password file: open ~/RPI/filename.sec: no such file or directory. But it exist [linux]

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, command-line

Trying to run .sh file. with `--password "~/RPI.filename"`in it. Should read the `filename` but getting an error. Even though the file exists

error:

```
Fatal: Failed to read password file: open ~/RPI/filename.sec: no such file or directory
```

list of directories and files:

```
~/RPI$ l
g.json  m1/  m2/  filename.sec  startm1.sh*
```

I have used it before and I know the method works but no idea what on earth is happening here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your script is running in sh instead of bash ?  I think "~" is bash syntax.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There are 1½ issues here...

First, quoting a tilde prevents tilde expansion; compare `ls ~/RPI.filename` and `ls "~/RPI.filename"`

=> leave the tilde unquoted if you don't want a *literal* '~'

Second, is it `~/RPI.filename` or `~/RPI/filename`?